# Electronics Flicking on and off

Tags: toyota, ignition, electronics, celica

so last week I pulled the rocker cover off my Celica 7th gen to get at the broken lift bolts (typical), also cleaned MAF sensor and throttle body while I was at it.  After putting everything back together the engine is running really smooth.
However while I was driving all the electronics shut off and the engine stopped causing a jerk. Then after rolling a few meters it all came back on and the engine began firing again no problem. 
Now driving it around the electronics have been flicking on and off however not for long enough to stop the engine this time, only a really brief second. 
I've tested both ignition relays for appropriate resistance closed and open,  they close fine when connected to power.
Tested battery and alternator. Ignition switch seems to be fine. 
This car does have a chip in the key that allows for the ignition to supply power, perhaps the sensor is playing up but that is the last thing I can think of.
Any help is much appreciated because I'm stumped.
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!